# SAKIS 3G - Use of Google DNS

Tags: 12.04, dns

I am using UBuntu 12.04 LTS and I am using SAKIS 3G script to connect to my 3g wireless modem, i want to use google DNS by default , i don't know, how to use google DNS in sakis3g script.

In native Network manager,there is a box to change these values.

Tell me, how to configure this in sakis 3g script.

If this can be done via `/etc/sakis3g.conf` then what need to be entered in this file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial can work for you: [Click here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/03/how-to-setup-google-public-dns-servers-in-ubuntu-12-10-13-04-raring-ringtail/)

Comment: please mention related links in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to modify `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

1. Find the line that reads `#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;`
2. Replace with `prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;`

(Notice that we're also uncommenting this line so that it takes effect.)